# Calculate $(1+i)^{30}$ - an alternative solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Calculate $(1+i)^{30}$

I did this using the trigonometric form of a complex number, namely: 
$$1+i = \sqrt2 \left( \cos\left(\frac \pi 4\right)+ i\sin\left(\frac \pi 4\right)\right)$$
$$(1+i)^{30} = 2^{15} \left(\cos\left(\frac{15}{2}\pi\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{15}{2}\pi\right) \right)= 2^{15}(-i) = -2^{15}i$$

But then I thought perhaps I could do this using the exponential form of a complex number: 
$$1+i = \sqrt{2}e^{\frac\pi4 i}$$
$$(1+i)^{30} =  (\sqrt{2})^{30}e^{\frac {15}{2} \pi i } = 2^{15}(e^{\pi i})^{15/2} = 2^{15}(-1)^\frac{15}{2}$$ 
Now, my question is - is there a way to compute $(-1)^\frac{15}{2}$ over complex numbers?

Comment: $e^{30 \pi i/4} = e^{15 \pi i/2} = e^{8\pi i - \pi i/2} = e^{-i \pi/2}$.

Comment: No need to convert $e^{15 \pi i/2}$ to $(-1)^{15/2}$. Instead, when you get there, just use $e^{i \theta} = \sin \theta + i \cos \theta$. (Note that $(-1)^{15/2}$ is not uniquely defined: it could be either $i$ or $-i$ depending on whether you take $(-1)^{1/2}$ to be $i$ or $-i$.This can happen when you play around with complex real exponents.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $-1=i^2$ , so $$(-1)^{\frac{15}{2}} = (i^2)^{\frac{15}{2}} = i^{15} = i^{12}\times i^2\times i = -i$$

Answer (score 1):

use that $$(1+i)^2=2i$$ and so you must only compute $$2^{3}$$ and $$(i)^{30}$$ which is easy